# Is the space ($\Bbb R,d)$ totally bounded? compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $d(x,y) = | \arctan x - \arctan y|$. Is the space ($\Bbb R,d)$ totally bounded? compact?

How can I prove it is totally bounded? I assume if I can prove it then I can deduce that it is compact by Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem since it is also closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bolzano-Weierstrass doesn't apply to arbitrary metrics, just the traditional $|x - y|$ metric, so that's not going to work here.

For proving totally bounded, consider the function $f : (\mathbb{R},d) \rightarrow Y$ (where $Y$ is some subset of $\mathbb{R}$) given by $f(x) = \arctan(x)$. If you figure out what $Y$ is (draw a graph!) that should help you prove total boundedness.

And with a little more effort you can show $f$ is a homeomorphism, which will help you with the compactness question.